# calling template function of template base class

Tags: c++, templates, dependent-name

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Here's the code:

```
template<typename T>
class base
{
public:
    virtual ~base();

    template<typename F>
    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "base::foo<F>()" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
class derived : public base<T>
{
public:
    void bar()
    {
        this->foo<int>(); // Compile error
    } 
};
```

And, when running:

```
derived<bool> d;
d.bar();
```

I get the following errors:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
error: expected ‘;’ before ‘int’
```

I'm aware of [non-dependent names and 2-phase look-ups](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.19). But, when the function itself is a template function (`foo<>()` function in my code), I tried all workarounds only to fail.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`foo` is a dependent name, so the first-phase lookup assumes that it's a variable unless you use the `typename` or `template` keywords to specify otherwise. In this case, you want:

```
this->template foo<int>();
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245) if you want all the gory details.

Answer (score 13):

You should do it like this :

```
template<typename T>
class derived : public base<T>
{
public:
    void bar()
    {
        base<T>::template foo<int>();
    } 
};
```

---

Here is full compilable example :

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class base
{
public:
    virtual ~base(){}

    template<typename F>
    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "base::foo<F>()" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
class derived : public base<T>
{
public:

    void bar()
    {
        base<T>::template foo<int>(); // Compile error
    }
};

int main()
{
  derived< int > a;
  a.bar();
}
```